# Hashtag link CSS deteriorates when I reload the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, slider

I'm working on [this website](http://dlc.eugenenyawara.com). I'm implementing the [Moving Boxes jquery slider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/MovingBoxes/) at the bottom.

It works fine when I'm scrolling the items on the slider, but if I try to reload the page with the same URL link, the images fail to arrange as should. I'm customizing a responsive WordPress theme — could that be part of the problem, in that its CSS is interfering with the slider's CSS?

Comment: An example of such a broken link is like http://dlc.eugenenyawara.com/#&slider1=4

Comment: Nobody home at that URL.

Comment: What do you mean @Diodeus ? Please explain. It beats me.

Answer (score 0):

The image slider looks strange in Chrome - there are a series of rectangles over the images:
[image: slider rendering issue]

First port of call with any HTML/CSS issue would be to check your HTML is valid (say with [the W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/).  That shows you have some closing `</p>` tags without corresponding opening tags, for example:

```
<li> <!-- panel #3 --><br />
<a href="http://dlc.eugenenyawara.com">  <img src="/images/low-fat-cheese.png" alt="picture" /></a></p>
</li>
```

I can't see why that'd cause problems on reload, but it may have something to do what I'm seeing on Chrome.  Be interested to know if you still get issues once it's fixed.

Comment: Hello @Hobo. I fixed the <p> links. Doesn't solve a thing. Still looking for a solution :/

Comment: The good news is that's fixed the display issue I was seeing in Chrome.  The HTML is still invalid though.  Take a look at the validator link I mentioned.  Your markup contains things like `<li title="<a href="#">The first image</a><img src="/jcover/images/1.png" /></li>`, which is invalid.  Not saying that's the source of the problem, but things might be clearer once it's fixed.

Comment: Actually it didn't. I found a different plugin to use for the same; the jcoverflip: http://www.jcoverflip.com/demo . Thanks all the same; I will clean-up the invalid html as I work on the rest of the site!